# Сокращение слова «турецкий»

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, сокращения

Сокращение слова «турецкий» — ***турецк.***?
Типа *в переводе с турецкого* (такого плана конструкции)...

Comment: турецкий - тур.    https://popravilam.com/blog/sokrashcheniya-osnovnye.html#t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такое правило: прилагательные и причастия, оканчивающиеся на *-кий*, сокращают отсечением этой части слова.
Возможно, что составители общей таблицы пропустили *-ецкий*, потому что слов таких немного:
немецкий, турецкий, донецкий, кузнецкий, москворецкий, половецкий...

Если следовать правилу, то сокращенное прилагательное должно иметь такой вид: *турец.*
Но нет. Правильно: немецкий — *нем.*, турецкий — ***тур.*** (см. приложение А), русско-турецкий — *рус.-тур.*

Из [БРЭ](http://bre.mkrf.ru/geography/text/v/2002048):
В 1538 Си­нил был за­хва­чен **тур.** вой­ска­ми. По сви­де­тель­ст­ву пу­те­ше­ст­вен­ни­ка-гео­гра­фа Ч. Эв­лия, Си­нил был пе­ре­име­но­ван в И. (Иш­масль; **в пер. с тур.** – «ус­лышь Бог»).

[Сокращение слов и словосочетаний по ГОСТ Р 7.0.12-2011](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/docs?layout=item&id=16_15)